# Geocode on autocomplete click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geocode

This is the code I am working from:

http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/75/

```
var GeoCoded = {done: false};

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('ready!');
    autosuggest();
    console.log($('#myform input[type="submit"]'));
    $('#myform').on('submit',function(e){


        if(GeoCoded.done)
            return true;

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit stopped');
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('location').value;

        $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, 
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                //if you only want to submit in the event of successful geocoding, you can only trigger submission here.
                GeoCoded.done = true;
                $('#myform').submit();
            } else {
                console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                //enable the submit button
                $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',false);
            }


        });        

    });    

});
```

This works how I want BUT, I wanted to complete the geocode when someone clicks on the autocomplete. So, when they type something and click on a suggestion from the autosuggest list, it actually completes the geocode call when the click the result.

If anyone could tell me if this is possible I would really appreciate it, because I havent been able to figure out how to do it myself.
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete incorporates geocoding automatically. [**Example here.**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/ac.html)

**Edit:**

Here is the gist of that example:

The key lines for creating the autocomplete control are:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
    types: [],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

You also need to load the Places library:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

and in your HTML:

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" value="">
```

By the way, you don't "add autocomplete to the geocoder".The Places Autocomplete class includes geocoding capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesnt seem to work on mine though, if you click my jfiddle it doesnt geocode on click

Comment: Then implement your autocomplete like my example, (which works), and not like your jsFiddle (which doesn't). ;-)

Comment: Ill give it a go and report back, I dont fully understand your code yet